# Удалить елемент из dict

Tags: python, массивы, list, словари

Есть json из него делаю dict

```
{
    "channels": [{
            "base": "",
            "name": "",
            "id": -1001290701457,
            "reserve": {
                "ru": [{
                    "name": "",
                    "url": "",
                    "id": -1001270940473
                }],
                "en": [{
                    "name": "",
                    "url": "",
                    "id": -1001633985636
                }]
            }
        },
        {
            "base": "",
            "name": "",
            "id": -1001388624580,
            "reserve": {
                "ru": [{
                    "name": "",
                    ",url": "",
                    "id": -1001270940473
                }],
                "en": [{
                    "name": "",
                    "url": "",
                    "id": -1001633985636
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Нужно удалить из массива reverse.ru значение с ид -1001270940473
Делаю вот так

```
for ch in data["channels"]:
    if int(group) == ch["id"]:
        for lol in ch["reserve"]:
            for jk, value in ch["reserve"][lol].items():
                print(jk, value)
                if int(jk["id"]) == int(id):
                    del jk
                    print(data)
                    break
        break
```

Но не получается

Comment: `ch["reserve"][lol]` - это список, по нему нужно ещё проитерироваться, а внутри него уже словарь, от которого можно брать `items()`

Comment: И зря вы не пишете, что значит "не получается". У вас должна получаться ошибка, которую и нужно было привести в вопросе.

Comment: а как удалить значение

Comment: @CrazyElf там не будет ошибки от питона. он просто удаляет копию того, что ему нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Имя `id` в питоне зарезервированно. Называть так переменную - плохо. Я переименовал её в `_id`.
Можно так:

```
for channel in data['channels']:
    if int(group) == channel['id']:
        for i in reversed(range(len(channel['reserve']['ru']))):
            if channel['reserve']['ru'][i]['id'] == int(_id):
                del channel['reserve']['ru'][i]
                break
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

***Если мы полностью уверены, что структура данных всегда будет соответствовать заявленной в задании, то предлагаю такое решение:***

```json
data = {
    "channels": [{
        "base": "",
        "name": "",
        "id": -1001290701457,
        "reserve": {
            "ru": [{
                "name": "",
                "url": "",
                "id": -1001270940473
            }],
            "en": [{
                "name": "",
                "url": "",
                "id": -1001633985636
            }]
        }
    },
        {
            "base": "",
            "name": "",
            "id": -1001388624580,
            "reserve": {
                "ru": [{
                    "name": "",
                    ",url": "",
                    "id": -1001270940473
                },
                    {
                        "name": "",
                        "url": "",
                        "id": -1001633985636
                    }
                ],
                "en": [{
                    "name": "",
                    "url": "",
                    "id": -1001633985636
                }]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
from pprint import pprint

_id = -1001270940473

for item in data.get('channels', []):
    item['reserve']['ru'] = [
        *filter(
            lambda x: x.get('id') != _id,
            item.get('reserve').get('ru', [])
        )
    ]
pprint(data)

#{'channels': [{'base': '',
#               'id': -1001290701457,
#               'name': '',
#               'reserve': {'en': [{'id': -1001633985636,
#                                   'name': '',
#                                   'url': ''}],
#                           'ru': []}},
#              {'base': '',
#               'id': -1001388624580,
#               'name': '',
#               'reserve': {'en': [{'id': -1001633985636,
#                                   'name': '',
#                                   'url': ''}],
#                           'ru': []}}]}
```

***Если же возможны варианты, то можно предложить следующее решение:***

```py
from itertools import starmap
from pprint import pprint
from typing import List

def dictfilter(obj, excluded: List[int]):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):

        if obj.get('id') not in excluded:
            for key, value in obj.items():
                obj[key] = dictfilter(value, excluded)
        else:
            return
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [
            *filter(
                lambda x: isinstance(x, dict),
                starmap(
                    dictfilter,
                    [(item, excluded) for item in obj]
                )
            )
        ]

    return obj


pprint(
    dictfilter(data, [-1001270940473])
)
#{'channels': [{'base': '',
#               'id': -1001290701457,
#               'name': '',
#               'reserve': {'en': [{'id': -1001633985636,
#                                   'name': '',
#                                   'url': ''}],
#                           'ru': []}},
#              {'base': '',
#               'id': -1001388624580,
#               'name': '',
#               'reserve': {'en': [{'id': -1001633985636,
#                                   'name': '',
#                                   'url': ''}],
#                           'ru': []}}]}
```

> ***Данный вариант удалит все элементы id которых находятся в списке `excluded`***